# How to know if the user has the application open

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm working on push notifications and I need to know if when a push notification arrives, the user has the application in foreground or not in order to show such push notifications or perform another action.

I'm using a custom receiver extending from ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.

If any have idea please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a single entry point to your app eg: MainActivity ?

Comment: Yes! I have a MainActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate class as follows -

```
      public class MyVisibilityManager {

private static boolean mIsVisible = false;

public static void setIsVisible(boolean visible) {
    mIsVisible = visible;
}

public static boolean getIsVisible() {
    return mIsVisible;
}
```

}

Create a base activity class, in its onresume set mIsVisible to true and onPause set it to false. and in your broadcast receiver you can check if mVisible is true or false and perform relevant actions.

Answer (score 2):

Create an application class as below. If you already have one, include the following

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private boolean isAppInForeground;

    public static boolean isAppInForeground(Context context){
        MyApp app = (MyApp) context.getApplicationContext();
        return app.isAppInForeground;
    }

    public static void setAppInForeground(Context context, boolean isInForeground){
        MyApp app = (MyApp) context.getApplicationContext();
        app.isAppInForeground = isInForeground;
    }
}
```

Create a BaseActivity like this and extend all your activities from this BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         MyApp.setAppInForeground(this, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MyApp.setAppInForeground(this, true);
    }
}
```

In your notification broadcast receiver's onReceive(), you can now check if app is in foreground

```
@Override
public void onRecieve(Context context, Intent intent){
   if(MyApp.isAppInForeground(context)){
       //app in foreground
   }
}
```